# Sorting based on frequency and position in python

Tags: python

I tried this code for input

3 2 4 6 2 4 3 3 4 5 6 3 2 4 5 5 3

```
import collections
numbers = input().strip().split(" ")
counter = collections.Counter(numbers)
sorted_list = sorted(counter.most_common(), key=lambda x: -x[1])
ans = [(v * n) for (v, n) in sorted_list]
for i in ans:
   print(" ".join(i),end=" ")
```

When I run this method

sometimes I get...

```
3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 5 5 5 6 6
```

(This is what I expect - first sort them based on frequency and then according to their order of appearance in the input)

sometimes I get...

```
3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 2 2 2 6 6
```

Essentially problem arises for same frequency numbers

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't specify how to sort when there is a tie, so the order is not guaranteed to be consistently the same

Comment: Thank you though...if a tie arises i should sort them based on their index(order of appearance in the input)... Can you suggest any improvements to be made to the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BIG UPDATE**

I agree with [MoxieBall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397416/1887559). The problem may be in the Counter object.

It seems OrderedDict can do a job, but you need to iterate through numbers in your code. Probably there is a better way to do that, but the code below should produce what you are looking for.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
numbers = "3 2 4 6 2 4 3 3 4 5 6 3 2 4 5 5 3".strip().split(" ")
counter = OrderedDict()
for n in numbers:
    counter[n] = counter[n]+1 if n in counter else 1
sorted_list = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x:-x[1] )
print sorted_list
ans = [ v*n for v,n in sorted_list]
print ans
for i in ans:
    print " ".join(i)
```

The output is that and never flips.

```
[('3', 5), ('4', 4), ('2', 3), ('5', 3), ('6', 2)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
['33333', '4444', '222', '555', '66']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
3 3 3 3 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
4 4 4 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
2 2 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
5 5 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
6 6
```

To double check that it is in the order of appearance, let's swap first 2 and last 5 in the string. For the string  "3 5 4 6 2 4 3 3 4 5 6 3 2 4 5 2 3" the output is following:

```
[('3', 5), ('4', 4), ('5', 3), ('2', 3), ('6', 2)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
['33333', '4444', '555', '222', '66']
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5
2 2 2
6 6
```

If your strings are quite long, you need to find a better way to fill the OrderedDict

Comment: The input that you have given has an extra 5 in it..;-)  The main problem is that i don't to sort the same frequency elements based on the value i.e., which is greater... I want to sort the same frequency elements based on their order of appearance... In this case i have  provided, 2 and 5 have same frequency = 3. So, i have to arrange based on order of appearance i.e., 2 appears first in the input so i have print that first before 5

Comment: I didn't get this from your question. Now it is more clear, what you are trying to achieve. I agree with @MoxieBall that the problem is inside collections object which probably uses a dictionary-like object.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this, but my guess is that it's because Counter makes a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are their frequencies. Since dictionaries don't guarantee ordering, it's a bad idea to depend on Counter to keep ties in the order they were first entered.

Answer (score 0):

I think* this sort key function should do the trick

```
lambda x:(-x[1],int(x[0]))
```

conversion will work as long as your numeric strings don't contain "," or anything in between